# Printf printing suspiciously large float

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

So currently im trying to print a float array (float *) containing some uninitialised float values. Somehow, in my console it shows values like this (using "%d: %f\n" as format):

```
-0.000000
0.000000
68509253839697691852885035134612406272.000000
0.000000
-0.000000
0.000000
```

This makes no sense to me. How can a float be so long?
Also, in a quite similar situation where im using sprintf with format "% 5.1f " to "toString" a matrix, my program gets aborted ("line 11:  1294 Abort trap: 6"):

```
void mat_print(char * buf, matptr_t mat) {
  char numbuf[10] = {0};
  strcpy(buf, "");

  for(uint32_t y = 0, ystop = mat->h; y < ystop; y++) {
    strcat(buf, y == 0? "[ " : "\n[ ");
    for(uint32_t x = 0, xstop = mat->w; x < xstop; x++) {
      // on x = 2, i get an abort
      sprintf(numbuf, "% 5.1f ", mat_get(mat, y, x));
      strcat(buf, numbuf);
    }
    strcat(buf, "]");
  }
}
```

here, im trying to get a value from a matrix object

```
struct matrix {
  uint32_t h, w;
  float * matrix;
};
typedef struct matrix * matptr_t;
```

with a function called mat_get

```
inline float mat_get(matptr_t mat, uint32_t y, uint32_t x) {
  return mat->matrix [y * mat->w + x];
}
```

the matrix float pointer array is pointing on an allocated region next to the matrix itself, its all allocated in one go:

```
matptr_t matrix(uint32_t h, uint32_t w) {
  // nn_allocator is a function pointer to malloc
  matptr_t mat = (matptr_t) nn_allocator(sizeof(struct matrix) + h * w * sizeof(float));
  mat->h = h;
  mat->w = w;
  mat->matrix = (void *)mat + sizeof(struct matrix);
  return mat;
}
```

the large floats are printed with:

```
// matptr is a pointer to a matrix object
float * values = (matptr)->matrix;
for(uint32_t i = 0, stop = (matptr)->w * (matptr)->h; i < stop; i++, values++) {
  printf("%d: %f\n", i, *values);
}
```

So the question is: **How can this code be fixed so it doesnt abort my program anymore and why is this float so long?**

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just a thought, if you're "printing" to `numbuf`, a 10-character array, a number which will involve more than 10 characters, wouldn't that be a natural source of "my program gets aborted"?

Comment: To see the largest float value, try `printf("%f\n", FLT_MAX);`. You'll need to `#include <float.h>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, apparently, i forgot to specify an upper bound to these numbers, which was actually my plan.  :)

Comment: is there a way to "truncate" floats if they are too long?

Comment: You can use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean truncate it?  You can limit the number of digits by using scientific notation eg `printf("Float max: %.4g\n", FLT_MAX);` -    From the man page, on %g 'Style e is used if the exponent from its conversion is less than -4 or greater than or equal to the precision.  Trailing zeros are removed from the fractional part of the result; a decimal point appears only if it is followed by at least one digit

Comment: You can use an `%e` or `%g` format to have control of the number of digits printed regardless of the magnitude of the number.  When printing a float `x` according to a `%f` format, however, you will always get at least log10(abs(x)) digits.

Comment: I deleted my incorrect answer, but wanted to point out that the `void*` pointer arithmetic in `(void *)mat + sizeof(struct matrix)` is undefined behavior. You probably want something more like `(float*)((char *)mat + sizeof(struct matrix))`.

Comment: so i fixed it by clamping the value between -4096 and 4096, it works enough for me. Thaks for all you answers!